# Evosuite (maven) Unable to generate test / edit: tried eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, evosuite

[image]

I was testing evosuite (automation tool to generate junit test) using Maven plugin in Eclipse Luna, using JDK 1.8

I have followed the tutorial given in evosuite tutorial: http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/tutorial-part-2/

Able to generate test using the tutorial file provided by evosuite but when I tried it on one of the projects that I am working on, it couldn't generate test when I initiate mvn evosuite:generate in cmd.

understand that I first need to do a mvn compile and it actually generate all the .class files in the folder "target\classes", I actually checked that the physical files are indeed present in the folder "Classes". the folder structure is exactly the same as in the folder "src\main\java".

when I initiate "mvn evosuite:generate" , 
it actually started generating, 
it is showing:

> [INFO] Registered remote process from /127.0.0.1:58449
>   [INFO] Going to execute 139 jobs
>   [INFO] Estimated completion time: 278 minutes, by 2018-04-22T05:33:27.051
>   [INFO] Going to start job for: "Java file". Expected to end in 1158 seconds,
>   by 2018-04-22T01:14:45.848

and it continues until the very last java file,
showing this:

> [INFO] * Updating database to "java file name"

then it came to this:

> === CTG run results ===
>   [INFO] Removed test suites: 0
>   [INFO] New test suites: 0
>   [INFO] Missing classes:
>   [INFO] "Java file name"

and ended with this statement

> [INFO] WARN: failed to generate tests for 139 classes out of 139
>   [INFO] Stopping spawn process manager
>   [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>   [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 52:44 min
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-22T01:47:02+08:00
>   [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------

I am wondering if i miss out any steps? Because using the same steps I am able to generate the test cases using the tutorial_maven provided by evosuite.

Or is this due to the complexity of the project and java files that evosuite is unable to process and generate the unit test?

Please advise! Thank you! i have tried many many different methods, mvn clean install repeatedly, but to no avail.

edit: tried eclipse plugin for evosuite as well: got the same error saying cannot find test.java file which is weird. Isn't the plugin supposed to generate the test file?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem? I am using the same tutorial and I have a similar problem